# How to make logistic regression with fashion-MNIST dataset

Tags: python

I don`t know what to do next , i tried many times, but my teacher wants me to make 10 models.

```
 import pandas as pd
from numpy import reshape
from sklearn import metrics

train = pd.read_csv('fashion_train.csv',header =None)
print(train.head())
label = train[0]

test = pd.read_csv('fashion_test.csv',header = None)
print(test.head())
labelT = test[0]
print(labelT)
X_train = train.iloc[:, 1:]

print(X_train)

y_train = train.iloc[:, 0]
print(y_train)

X_test = test.iloc[:, 1:]
y_test = test.iloc[:, 0]

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay So what you need to do now is to train your model. So just add the following lines to your code.

```
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
prediction = model.predict(X_test)
```

Now you can use any accuracy calculator. For example:

```
score = sklearn.metrics.classification_report(y_test, prediction)
print(score)
```

also I suggest change the import to `import sklearn`